# Sum the value based on the month of the date instead of days of the date in datetime format not string format

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Here is the data frame df showing sum of gross activations based on the days of date like the image given below. I did it using the following code

```
df1.groupby(df1['DATE']).sum()
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kJ0R.png)

```
    GROSS_ACTIVATION
DATE    
2020-08-01  35.0
2020-08-02  46.0
2020-08-03  72.0
2020-08-04  67.0
2020-08-05  70.0
... ...
2023-07-28  80.0
2023-07-29  80.0
2023-07-30  116.0
2023-07-31  147.0
2023-08-01  124.0
```

I want it aggregated based on the months of the date like the way given below. I tried it using the code  given

below

```
df1=(df1.groupby(df1['DATE'].dt.strftime('%m-%Y')).agg(GROSS_ACTIVATIONS = ('GROSS_ACTIVATION' , 'sum')))

df1
```

[image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLH3V.png)

```
         DATE    GROSS_ACTIVATIONS
    01-2021 2293.0
    01-2022 4383.0
    01-2023 3213.0
    02-2021 2274.0
    02-2022 3049.0
    02-2023 3195.0
    03-2021 2484.0
    03-2022 3540.0
```

but the problem is I want the following Date column **in datetime format instead of string format**  .

what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is what `resample` is for:

```
output = df1.resample(on="DATE", "M").sum()
```

Comment: Not exactly, `resample` will add all intermediate periods in case of a large gap, which may or may not be wanted ;)

Comment: @mozway - Ah, good point. But looks like the input is daily so that should not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `pandas.to_datetime()` function:

```py
df1['date_as_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.DATE, format='%m-%Y')

print(df1.dtypes) #Should show that the new column is a DateTime type
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the dates to monthly period, optionally getting the start of the period:

```
group = df1['DATE'].dt.to_period('M').dt.start_time

df1.groupby(group).sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use to_datetime as below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'])
df1=(df1.groupby(df1['DATE'].dt.strftime('%m-%Y')).agg(GROSS_ACTIVATIONS = ('GROSS_ACTIVATION' , 'sum'))).reset_index()
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'], format='%m-%Y')
print(df1.dtypes)
```

Output:

```
DATE                 datetime64[ns]
GROSS_ACTIVATIONS             int64
dtype: object
```